# Parameter passed in GLSL function not recognized as a constant

Tags: glsl

I'm doing an exercise in Shader School in which I implement a function that returns the nth power of a matrix.  Even when I pass constant parameter n into the following function:

```
mat2 matrixPower(highp mat2 m, const int n) {
    if(n==0) {
        return mat2(1.0);
    } else {
        mat2 result = m;
        for(int i=1; i < n; ++i) {
            result = result * m;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Loop index cannot be compared with non-constant expression
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `const` indicates that `n` is not writable, but it is still a variable and not a constant!
`n` varies with the actual parameter to the formal parameter when the function was called.

Note in Appandix A of [The OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) are listed possible limitations for OpenGL ES 2.0:

> for loops are supported but with the following restrictions:
>
> - condition has the form
>   `loop_index relational_operator constant_expression`
>   where relational_operator is one of: `>` `>=` `<` `<=` `==` or `!=`

In Chapter 5.10 Constant Expressions of [The OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) is clearly said, that a const function  parameter is not a constant expression:

> A constant expression is one of
>
> - a literal value (e.g., 5 or true)
> - **a global or local variable qualified as const excluding function parameters**
> - an expression formed by an operator on operands that are constant expressions, including getting
>   an element of a constant vector or a constant matrix, or a field of a constant structure
> - a constructor whose arguments are all constant expressions
> - a built-in function call whose arguments are all constant expressions, with the exception of the texture lookup functions.

A workaround would be to create a loop which is limited by a constant expression and to `break` out off the loop with a condition:

```c
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if ( i >= n )
        break;
    result = result * m;
}
```